# Hyperledger Fabric - Timeout instantiating chaincode

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I have issues instantiating my chaincode on a channel (timeout), and as I'm quite new to Docker and containerisation it may come from network setup.

Here is the command:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ControlTowerMSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@controltower.com/msp" peer0.controltower.com peer chaincode  instantiate -C frenchspoonchannel -n nodecc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}'
```

The chaincode container is created but not up and the command timeout

**Peer logs:**

```
2018-12-05 13:46:20.263 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 036 [frenchspoonchannel][b33ded8e] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while starting chaincode nodecc:1.0 for transaction b33ded8e61c100521c4e08ab9402b5324cb967f63e1163d1963e2293ce0445f6
```

**dev-peer logs:**

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/src/chaincode_example02.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! chaincode_example02@1.0.0 start: `node chaincode_example02.js "-- peer.address" "192.168.176.5:7052"`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chaincode_example02@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**Orderer & Peer docker-compose.yaml**

```
orderer.com:
container_name: orderer.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
environment:
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
command: orderer
ports:
  - 7050:7050
volumes:
    - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/controltower.com/orderers/orderer.controltower.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/controltower.com/peers/devpeer/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer0.controlTower.com
networks:
  - controltower.com

 peer0.controltower.com:
container_name: peer0.controltower.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
environment:
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.controltower.com
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ControlTowerMSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.controltower.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=p0.controltower.co:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=p0.controltower.co:7051
  #- CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=peer0.controltower.com:7052
  # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
  # # bridge network as the peers
  # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_controltower.com
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
  # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
  # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
  # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: peer node start
# command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
ports:
  - 7051:7051
  #- 7052:7052
  - 7053:7053
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/controltower.com/peers/devpeer/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/controltower.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - ./chaincode:/etc/hyperledger/chaincode
depends_on:
  - orderer.com
  - couchdb
networks:
  - controltower.com
```

As you see I tried with the env var chaincode.listen.address and open new port 7052 but it didn't work.

Thanks !